Dot Net framework error initialization problem
enter image description here
Error displayed when turn on pc , and install windows apps
I tried to install . Net frewoek v4. D
How can I fix it , I have windows 10 . Please I want to know if the problem from the windows itself.
I opened control panel and added dot net framework  that is available on my pc .
And everything it is not able to install.
